# Entering ascii into html text box

Tags: html, textbox, ascii, buffer-overflow

I'm doing a cybersecurity capture the flag challenge and attempting to do buffer overflow on a server. it has an html text box that I'm trying to overflow with particular values. How can I enter ascii characters into this text box? The characters entered after a certain buffer length seem to be converted into their ascii values, so I'm trying to enter characters like NUL, EOT, etc. into the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hex value, see [this](https://www.asciitable.com/) or [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html)
For example from python you could use something like:

```
param = "\x00\x04\x03\x03"
```

And then send as GET request (see urllib2 or requests or httplib2)

From URL, before of the hex code you must add the `%` character

```
yourpage.html/param=%00%04%03%04
```

Look also this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm)

Comment: I also ended up needing to add the `$` character before the hex values